# Saving a excel file in frontend retrieved as byte array from api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, closedxml, filesaver.js

I'am trying to return a Excel file as a byte array from a ASP.NETcore API with a ajax post, but I have some problems.

I know it is easier to return a IActionResult, but for this case I need it to be in a ajax call.

The backend seems to work somewhat. I create the excel report and return a byte array:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/excel/")]
    public byte[] ExportToExcel([FromBody] List<CarReports> carReports)
    {
        var orderReports = monthlyReports.OrderBy(x => x.Project.Code).ToList();
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Fakturering");

        // Here I create the excelsheet
        
        var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.SaveAs(returnStream);
        byte[] arr = returnStream.ToArray();
        returnStream.Flush();
        returnStream.Close();
        return arr;
    }
```

In the frontend I use filesaver.js to create a blob and save as:

```
export function excelExport(filteredReports, type){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: EXCEL_EXPORT, filteredReports, type });
        dispatch(loading());
        return client.excelExport(filteredReports, type)
            .catch(errors => {
                dispatch({type: EXCEL_EXPORT_FAIL})
                dispatch(error(errors))
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                const blob = new Blob([response], {
                    type:
                      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                  }); 
                  fileSaver.saveAs(blob, "test.xlsx");
                  dispatch(done());
            });
    }
}
```

The code seems to work, but when i open the file it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like the byte array has been put in the excel sheet.
Does anyone know what i'am doing wrong? Maybe i'am approaching this all wrong

Comment: For one you're not setting `Content-Type` header.  You would be better off using `IActionResult` and returning [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult).

Comment: I actually tried that, but that didn't work for me. I decided to write the excel in the frontend instead using exceljs. Thanks

Comment: I ended up writing everything in the frontend. Since i already had all the data on the client side i used the react library exceljs to recreate it.